# Manhwa where female protagonist is transmigrated to a game she plays once she obtains certain amount of diamonds

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character in this manhwa (a woman with brown hair) was playing a game, something like *gnomes mining for diamonds*. The game gives an unknown gift to a player when they reach 1,000,000 diamonds. Because she was so close to the number, she decided to buy some diamonds and reach a million.

I don't remember what happened after that, but the reward was that she was dragged to a different world, but she still had her phone and the game.

She became rich in that world and was able to summon something out of seeds which I don't remember.

She has one holy white envious arrogant seed, a common little girl seed, and a warrior with black hair I think seed. The arrogant seed was raised by the warrior seed

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this ***[Terrarium Adventure](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/kkpnm48/terrarium-adventure)***...?

> "I'm a zillionaire in a gacha game!"
> Obsessed with the clicker game Infinite Diamonds for over a year, Jaehee finally reaches the ultimate in-game achievement — only to suddenly find herself in the RPG gacha game Terrarium Adventure! Why was she pulled into the game, and how can she get out? For now, she has no choice but to explore!

The main character, a brown-haired woman, is really into 'Infinite Dia,' a smartphone game where you collect diamonds gathered by miner gnomes. In the game, there's a special achievement you can get for collecting 999 trillion diamonds.

She unlocks that achievement and is then transmigrated into the game world of 'Terrarium Adventure,' a new game by the same developer which is due to replace Infinite Dia. This game involves Dryads, people grown from plant seeds.

She meets a common girl early on, who she later learns is a Dryad. She also grows two Dryads herself from seeds; one a condescending man in priest-like robes, and the other, a male knight in dark armour.

[image] [image]